# How to simplify defining a long union type in TypeScript type definition

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

### problem

i want to declare a type just number of pow of 2, range from 1 to 2^30, like this:

```
declare type A = 1 | 2 | 4 | 8 | ... | 1073741824
```

but i don't want to write too many numbers.

Is there any simplified ways?

### trys

i try to declare a type helper to init a type of 10 numbers range 0 to 9, like this:

```
type FlagHelper<N extends number, R extends number[] = []> = 
    R['length'] extends N 
        ? R[number] 
        : FlagHelper<N, [...R, R['length']]>

type A = FlagHelper<10>
// type A = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 9
```

so i just only change `:FlagHelper<N, [...R, R['length']]` to `:FlagHelper<N, [...R, 1 << R['length']]` can feed my need.
but TypeScript type definition do not support any operators like `+,-,*,<<` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done but range is limited:

```
type ArrLen2PN<
    EXP1 extends number, 
    Accum extends any[] = [any], 
    Count extends number[] = []> = 
    EXP1 extends Count["length"] ? Count :
        ArrLen2PN<EXP1, [...Accum, ...Accum], [...Count, Accum["length"]]>

type POWS = ArrLen2PN<13>;
// type POWS = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096]
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAMhAdgJgAoDkA8BRADQwEYoIAPYVAEwGcoUBXAWwCMI4AaWAYx5bKUa9AIYoQAbQC6UALxQJYkFO4BhAPaMUwQVRR0GLdnGlyFUgHxmAUFDtRCJXcKgatwCQCIANqgDmwAAWnjIA-K6a2lAAXLb28fBIqJi4jsTcEgB02TB8LNzZmbn8zCoKhW7a3MUsXr4oAcFSltagkFAYAPIA6gDKZonI6Ng4xADMFgDc1tZAA)

In the typescript playground, using exponent larger than 13 results in an error.

At 14 the error message is

```
Type produces a tuple type that is too large to represent.(2799)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't *really* do math with types. Well you sort of can, but as you noticed, it involves building tuple types of specific lengths to represent integers.

See: https://itnext.io/implementing-arithmetic-within-typescripts-type-system-a1ef140a6f6f

Which means that if you want to derive `2^30` in a type you'll have to, eventually, create a tuple type with a length of `2^30`.

And that simply isn't going to work:

```
// Creates a tuple type of length `N`.
type Tuple<N extends number, Current extends any[] = []> =
  Current["length"] extends N
    ? Current
    : Tuple<N, [unknown, ...Current]>

type A = Tuple<1073741824>
// Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)
```

Here Typescript tries to execute that recursive type 1 billion times, and then gives up before it finishes to prevent running of memory and/or monopolizing your CPU.

`Tuple<999>` seems to be the highest it will go before giving up, which puts you 6 orders of magnitude away from your goal. That is not a small gap.

---

But it's not like the powers of two will ever change, nor is it a very large list.

So I'd just write some code to generate this type for me, like say:

```js
function createPowersOfTwoType(maxPower) {
  const values = []

  for (let i = 0; i <= maxPower; i++) {
    values.push(Math.pow(2, i))
  }

  const lines = values.map(value => `  | ${value}`).join('\n')
  return `Type A =\n${lines}`
}

console.log(createPowersOfTwoType(30))
```

And paste the result into your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to generate the full range of the safe 53 power-of-two number types,

```
type PowersOfTwo = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536, 131072, 262144, 524288, 1048576, 2097152, 4194304, 8388608, 16777216, 33554432, ...
```

with a builtin startup runtime check (`startupCheck`) to confirm the literal chosen power of two values.

If the `PowersOfTwo` array is 53 or longer, or any of the literal values in `PowersOfTwo` are incorrect, then `startupCheck` throws an error.

*(Note: I used github's co-pilot to generate the values, so it is absolutely necessary to check they are correct! As it happens, they were not correct much above 2**53. which is over MAX_SAFE_INTEGER anyway.)*

Because `powersOfTwo` is declare with `const ... as const`, it becomes a Tuple Type, and `type PowersOfTwo = typeof powersOfTwo[number]` generates a type of types array.

```
/**
 * The values in powerOfTwo were obtained using github co-pilot.
 * After writing the first line, co-pilot filled in subsequent lines one at a time,
 * requiring return after each one.
 * Interestingly, co-pilots guesstimates were not bigint worthy beyond MAX_SAFE_INTEGER!
 */
const powersOfTwo = [
    1, //1<<0,
    2, //1<<1,
    4, //1<<2,
    8, //1<<3,
    16, //1<<4,
    32, //1<<5,
    64, //1<<6,
    128, //1<<7,
    256, //1<<8,
    512, //1<<9,
    1024, //1<<10,
    2048, //1<<11,
    4096, //1<<12,
    8192, //1<<13,
    16384, //1<<14,
    32768, //1<<15,
    65536, //1<<16,
    131072, //1<<17,
    262144, //1<<18,
    524288, //1<<19,
    1048576, //1<<20,
    2097152, //1<<21,
    4194304, //1<<22,
    8388608, //1<<23,
    16777216, //1<<24,
    33554432, //1<<25,
    67108864, //1<<26,
    134217728, //1<<27,
    268435456, //1<<28,
    536870912, //1<<29,
    1073741824, //1<<30,
    2147483648, //1<<31,
    4294967296, //1<<32,
    8589934592, //1<<33,
    17179869184, //1<<34,
    34359738368, //1<<35,
    68719476736, //1<<36,
    137438953472, //1<<37,
    274877906944, //1<<38,
    549755813888, //1<<39,
    1099511627776, //1<<40,
    2199023255552, //1<<41,
    4398046511104, //1<<42,
    8796093022208, //1<<43,
    17592186044416, //1<<44,
    35184372088832, //1<<45,
    70368744177664, //1<<46,
    140737488355328, //1<<47,
    281474976710656, //1<<48,
    562949953421312, //1<<49,
    1125899906842624, //1<<50,
    2251799813685248, //1<<51,
    4503599627370496, //1<<52,
    /**
     * Typescript shows a subtle tooltip warning on numeric literal exceeding a safe limit
     * ~~~ Numeric literals with absolute values equal to 2^53 or greater are too large to be represented accurately as integers.(80008)
     * Below here, co-pilots generated values also got wonky, if you were expecting true bigint worthy values
     */
    9007199254740992, //1<<53,
    18014398509481984, //1<<54,
    36028797018963970, //1<<55,
    72057594037927940, //1<<56,
] as const;

// Converted to a Type
type PowersOfTwo = typeof powersOfTwo
// type PowersOfTwo = readonly [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536, 131072, 262144, 524288, 1048576, 2097152, 4194304, 8388608, 16777216, 33554432, ... 30 more ..., 72057594037927940]


/**
 * This startup check works as expected and catches over-MAX_SAFE_INTEGER error,
 * as well as checking that the numeric value is correct.
 */
function startupCheck(){
    for (let i in powersOfTwo){
        if (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER < powersOfTwo[i]){
            throw new Error(`startupCheck failed: powersOfTwo[${i}] >  Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`);
        }
        const expected = String(2n ** BigInt(i));
        const actual = String(powersOfTwo[i]);
        //console.log(`i: ${i}, actual: ${actual},  expected: ${expected}}`);
        if (expected !== actual) throw new Error(`startupCheck failed: powersOfTwo[${i}] actual: ${actual},  expected: ${expected}} `);
    }
    console.log("startupCheck passed");
}
startupCheck();


/**
 * This startup check (unexpectedly to me) passes, despite using bigints!
 * It is because the reverse type conversion from number value in powerOfTwo to bigint 
 * ends up being the correct bigint - I didn't expect that.
 */
function startupCheckNG(){
    for (let i in powersOfTwo){
        const expected = 2n ** BigInt(i);
        const actual = BigInt(powersOfTwo[i]);
        //console.log(`i: ${i}, actual: ${actual},  expected: ${expected}}`);
        if (expected !== actual) throw new Error(`startupCheckNG failed: powersOfTwo[${i}] actual: ${actual},  expected: ${expected}} `);
    }
    console.log("startupCheckNG passed");
}
startupCheckNG();
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#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-RTGciK0iMT6U4yZXO84mSQb5TSaXGCb3M0vo3bZ3qKaOC5PkwyaQS8-OJ6Ts3aMRHezyCUqG8X0fGIzLHZqVaSqynkTKNIyt2FLLj+fZNsGwHDoKV5pvK55agSToZk6LIcvKtYUlqWpnjynrodODKtjKWqjlqRZHgiZ4rg+Lb+gmcE7uiH49uGgGLrSJ7QkBvbYfGBIZuhN7ohi0FzlqyKMkhVH+vKj4tnG7ojnBf4Mo6WoakyYlzpxrImreHqSVOipxu2P7dghNJkeasY2nqVHnphpFjrh+oYmaV69rqMr4Xmo7mhuTIshuK4agGQGeQeGEWcxkKfoxwHdrpgohdxkDBgBvHRXGHJeSJmLuoJyHsXqsZ6Ra8m5khOECXmaZbkiyG6hKPLYThUkBneYFWjyBmiYqUKkWRqYRqWlU-hqCF9WuOG5oBn7IXp7bkqAEB2vUsAdKQeCKGYpAOLg8BUPgySBLwviWOQ5AYG0pBsGgxQWHEkBEFg6RmIojgyLQmCQIgAAeiiIEIFhnaUyBOKkMjkvUAB+COQFc720AQX1OMYNCYPglAyNUaBcLgN1YMYqCYEM-1hH9PCsBiAB68axDQUgcGMzOPcgNOsBgj3iJzrBcMgHCkBwwTNMIlSKEUYydAk+DEMYfN2NoAAUFLIhrFIAJSwzAABCiCaJQkBIBw3TuH0PADIg0RY8YwjoNgMTY6w4jTCwRAANZdIQDCQBsWBsC0-0AztihtEQkg8DQOAzHMCuLMs8CrI7Qy6+8dqSQBRmKsVGmNQi8a6urwbWbWjoWh6AYso+K5jpKpGfkWTrWZ+NdxZAGbInW+EOkBnqkQ6NdigAunLbhfDwADc4DgHCkAAMJxCgtD21dCRwNtiDgDwW+QAACr8dgAiwkAgrvO3kH7FDsP8TAsHPwCWHvh+3yfwLZBUghxLLoIwgqrghRSmCpAGKqUMqSlcIqZUGpOR6jAmaCaDo0KUg9HAv01dQFiQjK4WM75XCpnTJybq+ZXDjXLAQmsdZlTNlbOZbsSE+xAJHGOYBs55wgNXOuTcrhtB8NAciSAqQljID4doVwXce5IWRP3MS0iR5zzAFkBABB8D2EeoUe6VRECKE9onT2p18CAzDmvNARBhCKESNo-A5AV40BUDsA4xxziXBuPcJ4-0aA0CWGiGAaAcaGwwOPbRuiLCyESJYJAr0UafTJk7Qg+BlBeJ0ToN44AGBYCIOHAgL11HLCwKQBeSBdEqy1gAb3JAwJYkAVa+AcAQfwPw3733IOU2G6ICB+xVsjVIgsaDaEcUcU4Fxri3AeI8SACIml-HfqCAgI82kbSWZE7xxtojGzOF4pYKsAAGeTNFFJ0Xohg-BfCCAAFzTOPi00EAASMpBAAC+Y8AB8kIel9IGXsIZLjRnuMeDsrWM9lmQEee0yEnxvjGJSX4EEhxo4SBVhiEgYBIB6zmE0HgKsCBayBeCie3xKiFD+nChFkcVY3xmTc+ZeKQVwkhTdRA2hNDiF2QQS59ynmuCJVgTAHKyk8swI81wIcTFCH5dC8OQhHmPMBcC5ZnSamSrXs8IEIJBUYC1isqgr1EAbK2TQXZ+yCmHN0ZAE5GhxVXLvoCO5DznkJHDryjA-KNXCshMqq19zPWCBlZAOV5IwV2gZb4Zl5BWUACJjWFOKXo0g-jgiCAjXisF0bTWe1KTPWea1lHwFUZAaNShY01MyT62WNMhGIC1fG4YeBXCCDwOoUmogLCzHmFbV49QGj1PwILSxohOZRI4HY4Iz8doTxHTkkgDBvGpGib0kwqdkDECue-debaE5ZBtoIfABS1hhKiUkjg4c47tsgCoRokBBAEEEEQAA5A4ZVkTEh1BAO8DJWS2i5L4PkmNRyrh3FKRUu0VTma1MQPUxplLrmAkWcsyFj7Q4wuECCZF0B9YYoiNi2l8G4iEqdSStFmGsXQZtSwOZCz5VLPpXhxlYbWU7PZZATl7qNWuoIxgd1orkMSqQ1K31sqcNLMVSrH1kBVXqo41q2QqzdX6u8YavZP6DmxoA+a05VrSOzJY2PNjzGBUca4z63jYqBP+qE6C8kIamUspVlG5TJrVN3DIAmoQyaZ6poc3+3RAHM3gCAA)

Comment: "but i don't want to write too many numbers." says the OP. The point here is no hardcode the numbers at all.

Comment: @AlexWayne - I see your point. I felt it was addressed by semi-auto generation with github co-pilot. Of course AI can't be trusted 100%. The semi-auto generated numbers are not in a type, but in an ordinary JS object instance, so that can be checked at startup with `startupCheck`. The type is created from the object instance: `type PowersOfTwo = typeof powersOfTwo` so the type definition itself contains no numbers, which is good, because there is no way to runtime check the type values. (`enum` or an object with e.g. `1<<6` values is the normal way and it's enough, we're just having fun here.)